# applescript - How many days in a specific month (specified date)

Tags: applescript

Overview

- I'm trying to provide a specified date and find out how many days are in that month.
- Found something close but it uses current date.  How do I modify the current date so it accepts it in the subroutine input below

Desire:

- Get the Number of Days in a month from a specified date
- enter (MM/DD/YYYY) get the number of days

Sample:

```
on GetNumberOfDaysInMonth(aDate)
    local aDateCopy
    copy aDate to aDateCopy
    set day of aDateCopy to 1
    if month of aDateCopy is December then
        set year of aDateCopy to ((year of aDateCopy) + 1)
        set month of aDateCopy to 1
    else
        set month of aDateCopy to ((month of aDateCopy) + 1)
    end if
    return day of (aDateCopy - 1 * days)
end GetNumberOfDaysInMonth

my GetNumberOfDaysInMonth(current date)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I figured it out.

```
set newDate to current date

set the month of newDate to (2 as integer)
set the day of newDate to (1 as integer)
set the year of newDate to (2021 as integer)

my GetNumberOfDaysInMonth(newDate)
```

Comment: The `(n as integer)` is not at all necessary! Simply provide the _value_ by not quoting, e.g. `set the month of newDate to 2` and `2` in this case is an _integer_ already as it's not quoted. Same goes for `1` and `2001` in the remaining _code_. (You didn't use, nor need to, `as integer` in your _handler_, so why switch conventions in the other _code_.)

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, it's always more efficient to store a list of known quantities that can be looked up when required, rather than calling a handler (which is slower) and then having that handler perform a bunch of operations (which is slower still):

```
set numberOfDaysInMonth to {31, 28 + leap, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31}
```

where `leap` is given by the expression in terms of the year, `y`:

```
(y mod 4 = 0 and y mod 100 ≠ 0 or y mod 400 = 0) as integer
```

or, in a similar vain, could instead be stored as a pre-defined list.

That being said, below is a corrected/refined version of your handler.  Due to reasons, you're best not handling edge cases that arise in situations such as the December-into-January transition in the way that you have.  AppleScript `date` objects are designed to be adjusted by adding or subtracting a number of seconds.  Adjustments to any of its other properties (`day`, `month`, or `year`) require consideration of the knock-on effects such changes could potentially incur.

```
on numberOfDaysInMonth(input as {date, integer})
        local input

    if the input's class ≠ date then tell the (current date) ¬
            to set [input, day, its month] to [it, 1, input]
    tell the input to set [day, its month] to [1, 1 + (its month)]
    return the day of (input - days)
end numberOfDaysInMonth
```

This accepts an AppleScript `date` class object (such as that returned by **`current date`**, or simply a month represented either by its numerical value (1–12, which may be an `integer` or `string`/`text` class object) or as an AppleScript `month` class object (`January`, `February`, `March`, etc.—note that these are ***not*** string values).  Where a month is passed to the handler, it returns the number of days the month of the current year will (have) had.  Some examples:

```
get the numberOfDaysInMonth(current date)
        --> 31

get the numberOfDaysInMonth(December)
        --> 31

get the numberOfDaysInMonth(2)
        --> 28
```